# Test selection for group comparison

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test

We are running a study which investigates platelet aggregation changes during three trimesters of pregnancy and postnatal period. Then, we compare each of these phases to control non-pregnant women. The sample size is 46 including 10 per each trimester, 10 postnatal and 6 as control. The cases we recruited during these phases are not same women (i.e first trimester women are different from those of second trimester and so on). We used nine aggregation agonist for each group. We used Kruskal-Wallis Test to compare these five groups to each other as they are completely different then if we find p-value is significant, we performed PostHoc Mann-Whitney Test to find which two groups are exactly different in aggregation point of view. The questions here are:
1. Is it the right way to analyse the data in this study using the above tests and are we justified?
2. What are the limitations of using these tests?
3. Is there any better way to use in this research?

I will be very grateful for any kind of explanation.

Thank you very much in advance.